# How can I make follow form work with a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a relationship model that follow users back n forth
now it works very well when I use it in users#show in my view just like this screenshot

[image]

now this works good but what I have is a list of users.. and with that list I want to render similar type of follow form next to every item in list

here is the screenshot for reference

[image]

but of course this doesn't work because in my relationship controller I am finding user/amitian to follow with their id in params[:id] as in show page i have it but in my list page i don't

here is the code in controller for reference

```
def create
    @amitian = Amitian.find(params[:followed_id])
    current_amitian.follow(@amitian)
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @amitian }
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @amitian = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_amitian.unfollow(@amitian)
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @amitian }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

is there any solution for this so that I can render a follow_form in my listpage
it doesn't matter even if i have to render a new follow_form.. it just i want follow mechanism to work even from list page rather than only from show page of every user.

here is the show form in my show page..

show_form

```
<%if amitian_signed_in?%>
<% if @amitian != current_amitian %>
  <div id="follow_form">
  <% if current_amitian.following?(@amitian) %>
    <%= render 'unfollow' %>
  <% else %>
    <%= render 'follow' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
<%end%>
```

follow_form

```
<%if amitian_signed_in?%>
<%= form_for(current_amitian.active_relationships.build , remote: true ) do |f| %>
  <div><%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, @amitian.id %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Follow", class: "btn btn-primary form-control" %>
<% end %>
<%end%>
```

unfollow form

```
<%if amitian_signed_in?%>

<%= form_for(current_amitian.active_relationships.find_by(followed_id: @amitian.id), remote: true,
             html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-danger form-control" %>
<% end %>
<%end %>
```

Comment: Show the form which is on the 'show' page.

Comment: edited the post.. check now